# MassTransit/Rabbit MQ Version Compatibility

Tags: rabbitmq, compatibility, masstransit

Is a version of MassTransit tested and certified against specific versions of Rabbit MQ prior to its release? If so, is this information published?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the CI server, MassTransit is tested using the 3.6 version(s). Locally, I test it with 3.7.x, and recently 3.8.x. So it's a variety, depending upon what's installed.

Any relatively recent version of RabbitMQ (3.6.x or later) should work fine.

Update: According to AppVeyor, they use [v3.6.15-1](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/linux-images-software/)